# Radio buttons in rails not taking default value based on the data stored in the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, radio-button

Am trying to create a profile page where the user can check "male" or "female". After saving the form, whenever the user visits the page again, the gender must be set by default based on the data stored in the database.

Am using the form_for helper here.

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :gender, "Male", :value => "m" do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, "m" %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.label :gender, "Female", :value => "f" do %>
    <%= f.radio_button :gender, "f" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I this you should use like this way:

```
<% form_for( @profile) do |f| %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, "Male", :checked => @profile.is_male? %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, "Female",:checked => @profile.is_female? %>
<% end %>
```

In your models/profile.rb:

```
class Profile
  def is_male?
     #write your code for check male
  end

  def is_female?
     #write your code for check female
  end
end
```

Comment: def is_male?
    if self.gender == "m"
      return true
    else
      return false
    end
  end

Comment: still the radio button is not getting checked. I used the @profile.gender and checked it in the view, am getting the value "f".

Comment: Are you saving the gender as "m" or "f" in database?

Comment: In that case your form is not capturing the value properly